# Page lacks the HTML doctype, thus triggering quirks mode

Tags: html, doctype

When Running the Lighthouse PageSpeed Test, the Results are showing me that i have not declared a doctype. In the attached image you can see that there is a doctype declared.

Does anyone know why the test is giving me such an error?

Doctype is declared?!

[image: Doctype is declared?!]

The error from the PageSpeed Test

[image: The error from the PageSpeed Test]

Comment: The doctype is declared, but it's an XHTML doctype. These days, we'd use the HTML5 doctype, `<!DOCTYPE html>` and no `xmlns` declaration, etc.

Comment: I would consider the Lighthouse Pagespeed result a bug. All browsers I tested issue CS11Compat (i,e, Standards Mode) when checking pages with a legacy DOCTYPE declaration like HTML 4.01 or the above XHTML doctype. The very Wikipedia article the accepted answer linked to indicates indeed that no Quirks Mode should be triggered for correctly formed legacy doctypes. You certainly should not be using the HTML 5 doctype if it isn't HTML 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **a** Doctype, but the key is in the phrase "The HTML Doctype" which is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

You are using the Doctype for XHTML 1.0 Transitional, which is a legacy language. That Doctype triggers Almost Standards Mode instead of Standards Mode in a number of browsers where `<!DOCTYPE html>` would trigger Standards Mode.

See [the Wikipedia article on Quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) for more details.

An aside: While you have declared that Doctype, I see a `data-*` attribute in your screenshot so you aren't following it. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: This is not correct. All browsers I tested issue CS11Compat (i,e, Standards Mode) when checking pages with a legacy DOCTYPE declaration like HTML 4.01 or the above XHTML doctype. The very Wikipedia article you linked to indicates indeed that no Quirks Mode should be triggered for correctly formed legacy doctypes. You certainly should not be using the HTML 5 doctype if it isn't HTML 5.    So I would consider the LIghthouse Pagespeed response to this as a bug.

Comment: @Thomas — You should reread the Wikipedia article. Pay attention to [table that shows lots of doctypes that don't trigger standards mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types) and note that your test is probably flawed and using a JS property that reports CS11Compat for Almost Standards Mode as well as Standards Mode. As for your note about not using the HTML 5 Doctype unless you are using HTML 5 … as I pointed out in the answer: the OP is using the `data-*` attribute which was *introduced in HTML 5*.

Comment: The point is that a page with Almost Standards Mode fails the Lighthouse audit even though it has a valid Doctype declaration. I have posted this as an issue to the Lighthouse developer team on Github ( https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/14570 ) and they accepted it and developed a modification such that Lighthouse lets pages with Limited Quirks Mode pass the audit (still to be implemented apparently). -- Anyway, whether the HTML under the given Doctype declaration validates or not is a different questions that Lighthouse does not care about.